# Trouble with Regular Expressions replacing custom tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace

I have a simple editor that I allow people to update text on part of a website with.
I allow a couple of pseudo tags that I replace with html when I actually render their content. I'd like to use regular expressions to locate these tags and replace them with the appropriate html markup.

Basically there will be a block of text that may have one or more of the following embedded psuedo tags that I need to replace via regex using c#:

```
[E]me@myemail.com[/E]
```

needs to turn into

```html
<a class='LinkText' href='mailto:me@myemail.com'>me@myemail.com</a>
```

and

```
[L text='My Link Text']www.google.com[/L]
```

needs to turn into

```html
<a class="MyLinkClass" href="www.google.com">My Link Text</a>
```

For the email pseudo-tag I came up with the following Regex, but it doesn't work:

```
Content = Regex.Replace(Content, @"\[E\](?(email)[^<>]+)\[/E\]", "<a class='LinkText' href='mailto:?{email}'>?{email}</a>");
```

Since I'm stuck on this one I haven't made much headway on the other one either.

Any thoughts how I might get this to work? I've always struggle with syntax on these regular expressions... Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not parsing HTML. I'm parsing literal TEXT that has only those two pseudo tags contained within it.

Comment: Do you have to use only Regex?  I would do Regex to get the email.  Then I would use string.Format to create the replacement text.  Then you could just do a regular string replace.  Just an altenative idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

1. It looks like you're trying to use [named capture groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can create one of these inside of your regular expression using `(?<name>subexpression)`
2. When accessing a named capture group using `Regex.Replace`, you can access the named capture group using `${name}`.

Other than that you're pretty close. Here are two regular expressions that should be a good starting point:

Links:

```
string linkReplacement = 
    Regex.Replace(
        linkContent, 
        @"\[L text='(?<text>[^']*)'\](?<link>[^\]]*)\[/L\]", 
        "<a class='MyLinkClass' href='${link}'>${text}</a>");
```

Emails:

```
string emailReplacement = 
    Regex.Replace(
        emailContent, 
        @"\[E\](?<email>[^\]]*)\[/E\]", 
        "<a class='LinkText' href='mailto:${email}'>${email}</a>");
```

**Working example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhsoJ9

*Edit:* Updated to remove greediness.

Comment: I gave an upvote.  I like the use of named capture groups.  I haven't used those before :)

Comment: This worked like a charm! Was hoping to keep it as a one-liner and this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for making the syntax a little bit clearer on the named grouping, I think that was my biggest stumbling block.

Comment: Beware the greedy `.*`! (i.e. The above patterns have some serious issues - Be sure to test this solution with multiple tags on one line and tags which span multiple lines. The results may be surprising.)

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks for the disclaimer. This is meant to be a starting point and is by no means a complete solution.

Comment: @ridgerunner: I've updated the regular expressions. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Yes, much better. Although the: `[^\]]*` in each of the expressions would be better written as: `[^[]*` or possibly even: `[^[\]]*` - this will eliminate 3 unnecessary backtracks.

Answer (score 0):

Whipped this up in LINQPad...

```
void Main()
{
    string s = 
    @"[E]me@myemail.com[/E]
    blagra
    shlarga";
    foreach ( Match m in Regex.Matches( s, @"\[E\](\w+@\w+.\w+)\[/E\]") )
    {
      string emailMatch = m.Groups[1].Value;
      string entireMatch = m.Groups[0].Value;
      string replacement = string.Format( @"<a class=""MyLinkClass"" href=""{0}"">My Link Text</a>", m.Groups[1] );   
      string newString = s.Replace( entireMatch, replacement );
      newString.Dump();
    }

}
```

The second replacement is left as an exercise to the reader :) ;-)

You can simplify the line:

```
foreach ( Match m in Regex.Matches( s, @"\[E\](\w+@\w+.\w+)\[/E\]") )
```

to be:

```
foreach ( Match m in Regex.Matches( s, @"\[E\](.+)\[/E\]") )
```

if you want.